# How to detect "message type"-"message-handler" relation using reflection

Tags: c#

I have the following situation.
I have C# console application that receives TCP data in byte[] format.

I have a method called OnNetworkReceive that receives the byte[]

```
        public void OnNetworkReceive(NetPeer peer, NetPacketReader reader, DeliveryMethod deliveryMethod)
        {
            var packetType = (PacketType)reader.GetByte();
            var packet = NetworkUtils.ResolvePacket(packetType, reader);
            HandlerRegistry.Handlers[packetType].Handle(packet);
            reader.Recycle();
        }
```

1. `var packetType = (PacketType)reader.GetByte();` reads the first byte from the byte array and gets the type of the message.
2. `var packet = NetworkUtils.ResolvePacket(packetType, reader);` parses the rest of the message into C# struct.
3. `HandlerRegistry.Handlers[packetType].Handle(packet);` invokes the proper handler by using a predefined  dictionary that have the following structure.

```
    public static class HandlerRegistry
    {
        public static readonly Dictionary<PacketType, IPacketHandler> Handlers =
            new Dictionary<PacketType, IPacketHandler>
            {
                { PacketType.StartBattleRequest, new StartBattleRequestHandler() },
                { PacketType.ConfirmLoadingBattleScene, new ConfirmLoadingBattleSceneHandler() },
                { PacketType.EndTurnRequest, new EndTurnRequestHandler() },
            };
    }
```

PacketType enum:

```
    public enum PacketType : byte
    {
        None = 0,
        ConfirmLoadingBattleScene = 1,
        EndTurnRequest = 2,
    }
```

Here is an example of one of  the message handlers. Other handlers are identical:

```
    public class StartBattleRequestHandler : IPacketHandler
    {
        public void Handle(INetPacket packet)
        {
            var request = (StartBattleRequest)packet;
            System.Console.WriteLine($"[StartBattle] Attacker ({request.AttackerArmyId}) vs Defender ({request.DefenderArmyId})");
        }
    }
```

---

My question is:
Can you suggest what can I do to automatically populate HandlerRegistry.Handlers dictionary using reflection on startup.

I have good understanding of reflection, and I know that for example I can search for all classes that implement IPacketHandler, but the question is how can I know what is the PacketType that is associated with this message handler?

One idea that I have is each PacketHandler to have a readonly constant property that tells what is the PacketType that is associated with this him.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Use IoC container for resolving handlers. Use protobuf for deserialization/serialization of network messages. DryIoc have pretty good performance for high RPS environment, even better than simple dictionary (because it have it's own implementation for dependency graph resolution)

Comment: You can also entirely skip this micro-programming and use somethin from production-ready free libraries, for example Lidgren, instead of TCP/UDP  - https://github.com/lidgren/lidgren-network-gen3

Comment: Thanks for the advices guys,
@eocron I am currently experimenting with LiteNetLib, but I can also experiment with the library that you suggest.
https://github.com/RevenantX/LiteNetLib

Comment: Two questions: 1. are INetHandler and IPacketHandler your own types? Or are they defined elsewhere. 2. Can you use c#9?

Comment: With c#10, static interface members would make this a bit simpler. With c#9 you could manually define a self registration mechanism using module Initializers. Prior to c#9 the best you can do is really to add attributes to the type to designate the enum property and use reflection to find all types that are appropriately attributed. Otherwise you'd have to construct an instance just to find the property value (which may actually be alright since you are going to construct an instance anyways)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 
1. Yes they are my interfaces and they are very simple one.
2. I am using .net core 5 so I assume yes I should be able to use C#9, yes. -> IPacketHandler {void Handle(INetPacket packet);} | INetPacket { PacketType Type { get; } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options available to you. I outline three of them below in order of personal preference. I'm sure there are other ways to accomplish this, but these are what came to mind:

#### Option 1 - Module Initializer Registration

One option is to use C#9's Module Initializers and a self-registration feature. Module initializers are **guaranteed** to run before any other code in the assembly. You can declare more than one which is useful for this feature. First we can change your registry to something like this:

```cs
public static class HandlerRegistry
{
    internal static void Register(PacketType type, IPacketHandler handler)
        => Handlers[type] = handler;

    internal static void Register<THandler>(PacketType type) where THandler : IPacketHandler, new()
        => Handlers[type] = new THandler();

    private static readonly Dictionary<PacketType, IPacketHandler> Handlers = new();

    public static bool TryGetHandler(PacketType type, out IPacketHandler handler)
        => Handlers.TryGetValue(type, out handler);
}
```

And then have each handler type register itself. I've added two different `Register` methods depending on how you want to use them. From each class we need to call one of those methods. The `ModuleInitializerAttribute` must be placed on an `internal` or `public`  `static`  method and we can optionally hide it from intellisense with `EditorBrowsableAttribute`:

```cs
public class StartBattleRequestHandler : IPacketHandler
{
    [ModuleInitializer]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    internal static void Initialize()
        => HandlerRegistry.Register(PacketType.StartBattleRequest, new StartBattleRequestHandler());

    public void Handle(INetPacket packet)
    {
        var request = (StartBattleRequest)packet;
        System.Console.WriteLine($"[StartBattle] Attacker ({request.AttackerArmyId}) vs Defender ({request.DefenderArmyId})");
    }
}

public class EndTurnRequestHandler : IPacketHandler
{
    [ModuleInitializer]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    internal static void Initialize()
        => HandlerRegistry.Register<EndTurnRequestHandler>(PacketType.EndTurnRequest);

    public void Handle(INetPacket packet)
    {
        var request = (EndTurnRequest)packet;
        System.Console.WriteLine($"[EndTurn] TurnId {request.TurnId}");
    }
}
```

Then we can use the handlers as such:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var startRequest = new StartBattleRequest();
    var endRequest = new EndTurnRequest();

    if (HandlerRegistry.TryGetHandler(startRequest.Type, out var handler1))
        handler1.Handle(startRequest);

    if (HandlerRegistry.TryGetHandler(endRequest.Type, out var handler2))
        handler2.Handle(endRequest);
}
```

Which outputs:

> [StartBattle] Attacker (0) vs Defender (0)
>
> [EndTurn] TurnId 0

Note that I am assuming `INetPacket.PacketType` can be used here; otherwise you'd pass `PacketType.StartBattleRequest` directly. I've also made up a property on the `EndTurnRequest` just for demo purposes.

Now the downside to the above is that you need to clutter your handlers with an extra static method; but it does provide a nice mechanism that will guarantee registration even from external libraries (assuming they follow the convention and are statically referenced).

#### Option 2 - Reflection and Attribute

A second alternative is to query types with Reflection alongside a new attribute that we will apply to the handlers. This allows you to opt-in (or out) by using the attribute rather than just accepting any type implementing your interface.

The attribute:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public sealed class HandlerRegisterAttribute : Attribute
{
    public HandlerRegisterAttribute(PacketType type) => PacketType = type;
    public PacketType PacketType { get; }
}
```

And then add this attribute to your classes:

```cs
[HandlerRegister(PacketType.StartBattleRequest)]
public class StartBattleRequestHandler : IPacketHandler
{
}

[HandlerRegister(PacketType.EndTurnRequest)]
public class EndTurnRequestHandler : IPacketHandler
{
}
```

Now the tricky part. We need to build up the list of classes that:

- Implement our interface
- Are decorated with the `HandlerRegisterAttribute`
- Have a parameterless constructor
- Aren't abstract

Our updated `HandlerRegistry` now looks like this:

```cs
public static class HandlerRegistry
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<PacketType, IPacketHandler> Handlers = new();
    static HandlerRegistry()
    {
        var handlers = AssemblyLoadContext.Default
            .Assemblies
            .SelectMany(c => c.DefinedTypes)
            // Find concrete classes only
            .Where(c => !c.IsAbstract && !c.IsInterface && !c.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
            // Find only types implementing the interface
            .Where(c => typeof(IPacketHandler).IsAssignableFrom(c))
            // Find those with our attribute
            .Select(t => (type: t, att: t.GetCustomAttribute<HandlerRegisterAttribute>()))
            .Where(c => c.att != null)
            // Find those that have a parameterless constructor of ANY visibility
            .Where(c => c.type.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null) != null);

        foreach (var (type, att) in handlers)
        {
            if (!Handlers.ContainsKey(att.PacketType))
            {
                Handlers[att.PacketType] = (IPacketHandler) Activator.CreateInstance(type, nonPublic: true);
            }
            else
            {
                // decide if you ignore it OR overwrite it....
            }
        }
    }
    public static bool TryGetHandler(PacketType type, out IPacketHandler handler)
        => Handlers.TryGetValue(type, out handler);
}
```

The demonstration program above produces the same output. Note the comment at the end of the updated static constructor. You must decide what to do if you've found more than one class that says it can handle a particular `PacketType`. This method will find types with any visibility (`public`, `internal`) and will even use `private` constructors (the argument passed to `Activator.CreateInstance`). You'd need to tweak the various arguments to filter those out if you don't want them.

#### Option 3 - Reflection, added property and instantiation

We can forego the custom attribute if you are alright with adding a property to your `IPacketHandler` *and* constructing an instance of the type in order to inspect that property. For example, the updated interface and classes:

```cs
public interface IPacketHandler
{
    PacketType PacketType { get; }
    void Handle(INetPacket packet);
}
public class StartBattleRequestHandler : IPacketHandler
{
    public PacketType PacketType => PacketType.StartBattleRequest;
    public void Handle(INetPacket packet){}
}

public class EndTurnRequestHandler : IPacketHandler
{
    public PacketType PacketType => PacketType.EndTurnRequest;
    public void Handle(INetPacket packet){}
}
```

Now we can update the static constructor of the `HandlerRegistry` to find classes that implement the interface, construct an instance of them and look at the new property:

```cs
public static class HandlerRegistry
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<PacketType, IPacketHandler> Handlers = new();
    static HandlerRegistry()
    {
        var handlers = AssemblyLoadContext.Default
            .Assemblies
            .SelectMany(c => c.DefinedTypes)
            .Where(c => !c.IsAbstract && !c.IsInterface && !c.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
            .Where(c => typeof(IPacketHandler).IsAssignableFrom(c))
            .Where(c => c.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null) != null);

        foreach (var type in handlers)
        {
            // build our instance
            var instance = (IPacketHandler)Activator.CreateInstance(type, nonPublic: true)!;
            // inspect the new property
            if (!Handlers.ContainsKey(instance!.PacketType))
                Handlers[instance.PacketType] = instance;
        }
    }
    public static bool TryGetHandler(PacketType type, out IPacketHandler handler)
        => Handlers.TryGetValue(type, out handler);
}
```

Personally I don't like this option for a few reasons. First of all, it doesn't allow you to opt-in. Maybe that doesn't matter for your use case, but I always like being explicit about things. Second, I do not like instantiating the object so that we can inspect the property. In this case it doesn't matter so much since we are going to re-use the instance anyways. At least with the attribute approach it associates some metadata with the class.

Comment: This is brilliant. I don't have enough words to express my gratitude on the fact that you gave such and detailed answer! Each one of the suggestions will work for me. I will spend some time thinking about it and then pick one. To be honest maybe I will go with option 2 or 3, because there is a slight chance that I might need to be able to run my code on lower versions of C#. Thank you and have a great day!

Comment: Just quick mention. I implemented the attribute approach and it works like charm! Big thanks! :)